# Creating a MS PowerApps survey pre-populated with data

Tags: powerapps

The objective is to provide an annual survey for data gathering.  In the past we used third party web-based tools but these will not be allowed.

We do have SharePoint and PowerApps available to analyst users like myself.  I am not 100% sure about limitations like access to Dataverse.

Assume that employees Alice and Betty have completed surveys in the prior year for their client accounts.  Alice completed a survey for clients A1, A2; Betty completed a survey for clients B1, B2 and B3.

IS THERE A WAY...through the MS PowerApps environment...to create a survey pre-populated with last year's responses, and make it available to Alice and Betty for updating this year?  It is important that Alice and Betty cannot see each other's client information.

Thanks - I just want to know if I'm going down a blind alley.  I've seem plenty of "how to create a blank survey" or a "quiz" but nothing with these constraints.

Comment: Are the survey responses stored in Dataverse?  Is this a Canvas app?

Comment: shullaw I appreciate your response - This is purely in exploratory stage - I expect it would be a canvas app.  I think I will have to request Dataverse if necessary.

Comment: Yes @Valarenti your objective is feasible, but difficult to give any further input without more information

Comment: Thanks again @shullaw.
Again, appreciated shullaw.  I'll try to provide more info.  If I were using an SQL database to design this, I would envision the following tables:

Table1: SurveyQnA                 Table2: AccountReps
ClientName                             RepNameID
Q1                                           ClientName
Q2
Q3

The account reps will log into a canvas app and thereby be identified.
They will select from a drop-down the clientname, and this will retrieve the previous year's survey results, which they may choose to change or to leave as is for the current year.

Answer (score 1):

A simple, direct approach using a SharePoint List backend:

1. You should implement the row level security in SharePoint. Set the list's advanced settings to display to the users only their own records.
2. Add a form to your app to record a new response to the list (FormMode = New)
3. In the form screen's .OnVisible property create a context variable: UpdateContext({ varLastResponse: `Last(SurveyResponsesList) })`. If you set the advanced settings on SharePoint this will ignore other users' posterior responses.
4. Use the context variable to set the Default properties of the Form controls.

This will get you a prepopulated form to submit a new response.

In your question you wrote 'update'. I'm almost sure you meant updating the list, not the previous response, but just in case: To update the last response instead of creating a new one, set FormMode to 'Edit' and use the `Last(SurveyResponsesList)` formula from above in the Form.Item property. In this scenario there's no need to set the Default property for the controls.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.  I do believe I will be able to use the Dataverse as well but the Sharepoint List will definitely be more accessible.